# Visual studio code: intellisense not working, showing "initializing JS/TS language feature"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, intellisense, visual-studio-code

Intellisense isn't working in VSCode. Examples like:

- F2 (rename symbol): shows "initializing JS/TS language feature", but stucks forever [issue-image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32rEy.png)
- dropdown suggestions not coming up directly, ctrl+enter shows loading, but not getting completed
- doesn't show error even in case of genuine error, etc.

Already tried below things:

- restarted VScode multiple times
- Ctrl+Shift+P > typescript: Restart TS server --> nothing happens
- Installed & uninstalled extension (TSLint, JsHint, ESLint)
- "Help" -> "check for updates" --> says "there are currently no updates available"
- re-ran all command i.e. npm run setup-npm-auth, npm install etc.
- tried force build

{verified my solution is getting built properly}

Current versions:

- npm: 6.9.0
- node: 10.16.3
- [VScode version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kaluj.png)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it should be [filed as a bug report](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/new?template=bug_report.md)

Answer (score 3):

I resolved the issue by bumping op the "Max TS Server Memory". This reduced loading time exponentialy. I've set mine to 7072.

(Ctrl + ,) and search "memory".

[Settings in vs code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVT8Z.png)

Comment: This worked. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same issue. Fortunately I was able to fix the problem following this steps from vscode github's [comments](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/68896#issuecomment-465373515). You can enable ts language server's log and debug your issue. To enable ts server logging:

1. Set "typescript.tsserver.trace": "verbose" (Restart vscode)
2. Reproduce the problem
3. Open the output panel and view the TypeScript section

In my case my code was referencing to the directory outside of the workspace. So VSCode could never finish the task. I am not sure it's bug or limitation, nevertheless make sure all of your working code is included in your VSCode workspace (or added to working folders). Otherwise it'll stuck like this even code you're referring to exists side by side but not included in your workspace (or visible) in your VSCode.